# Editing a Cluster role provisioned via Helm using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I do have a terraform script which provisions a Kubernetes deployment and a few clusterroles and clusterrolebingings via Helm.

But now I do need to edit one of the provisioned Clusterroles via Terraform and add another block of permissions. Is there a way to do this or would I need to recreate a similar resource freshly.

This is my block to create the respective deployment for efs-csi-driver.

```
resource "helm_release" "aws-efs-csi-driver" {
  name             = "aws-efs-csi-driver"
  chart            = "aws-efs-csi-driver"
  repository       = "https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-efs-csi-driver/"
  version          = "2.x.x"
  namespace        = "kube-system"
  timeout          = 3600

  values = [
    file("${path.module}/config/values.yaml"),
  ]

}
```

Somehow I do need to modify https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/45c5e752d2256558170100138de835b82d54b8af/deploy/kubernetes/base/controller-serviceaccount.yaml#L11 by adding a couple of more permission blocks. Is there a way that I can patch it out (Or completely overlay)

Comment: Just modify your TF code. Not sure what is your issue? Can you please clarify and add TF code and what do you want to change?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. There are no variables there to make it customisable. However, there are two lines here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/charts/aws-efs-csi-driver/values.yaml#L79-L80 that might help.